# How skip line in Intellij idea debug?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

Suppose I have java code like this (only as Example):

```
public void someMethod(){
    int a = 3;
    int b = 2; // <-- stay debug here
    a = b + 2;
    System.out.prinln(a);
}
```

It is possible to skip execution of line `a = b + 2;` and go immidiatly to `System.out.prinln(a);`?

P.S. I use Intellij Idea 12.

Comment: "`int a = b+2;`" Can this compile?

Comment: Set Next Statement has been available in Visual Studio for many years.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's not possible with the debugger to not execute parts of the code.

It is however possible to execute extra code and change values on variables so if you need to exclude one row from execution during debug you will have to alter your code to prepare for that kind of debugging.

```
public void someMethod() {
    int a = 3;
    int b = 2;
    boolean shouldRun = true;
    if (shouldRun) {
        a = b + 2;
    }
    System.out.prinln(a);
}
```

You would then set a break point that changes the value of shouldRun without stopping execution. It can be done like this.

[image]

Note that

1. **Suspend** isn't checked
2. **Log evaluated expression** is used to alter a variable when the break point is hit

Comment: Wow that's an incredible solution. What a nice trick to have to just skip code execution, also have it on production code.

Comment: Can you also add hotkey or path for invoke this window? It is not cleare where you have this

Comment: It moves around. In 2016.2.5 I'm using ctrl+f8 and then ctrl+shift+f8 twice to get to that dialog.

Comment: In PhpStorm it is possible add `return [return value];` to _Watches_ and debugger will go out of the function

Comment: In IntelliJ it's also possible to Force Return or Throw Exception if you want to terminate the method execution in either way. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/altering-the-program-s-execution-flow.html#force_return

Answer (score 17):

IntelliJ recently published a blog post about a plugin called [Jump to Line](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14877-jump-to-line) that can accomplish this, even though IntelliJ itself doesn't have this functionality. It really is surprising that IntelliJ still doesn't have this functionality, when Visual Studio has had it for so many years!

https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/08/jump-to-any-line-while-debugging/

Comment: are you able to make it work? The plugin installed just fine in the latest version on ubuntu, but that special line doesn't show up. There are no other instructions - is there some shortcut I need to hit to make it appear? Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to skip lines only if you use hotswapping, or put in other words, code reloading tool - add code changes/new code at runtime. Hotswapping is the functions of replacing components without shutting down the system. Hotswapping can also refer to the ability to alter the running code of a program without needing to interrupt its execution.

There are various hotswapping tools like: JRebel (https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) or HotSwapAgent (http://www.hotswapagent.org/)

You avoid having to rebuild the entire application to reload code changes, this is a huge time savings. Instead of running your full build process, simply use the compiler built into your IDE and the hotSwap agent/tool will reload the code into the JVM.

In this case, it would not be actually skipping, but you can just comment/change the lines and reload it. This tools are quite awesome!!!! It greatly speeds up the development/debugging process.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just skip 'line execution' when debugging. You can press F8 to step over.

Answer (score 2):

An option is to skip the execution of the rest of the method. You can invoke `Force Return` and even set a return value.

Answer (score 0):

As stated here by ntotomanov , you can use HotSwap for it. 
but just adding that i use remote debug to debug my Docker based apps , so if i want this kind of functionality i just comment out the code , and go to Build -> Recompile class or Rebuild Project . then Intellij issues Build & Attempting to HotSwap the code ! in case you did small thing like comment out the code it most of the times always succeeds. happy debugging.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to skip the EXECUTION of the lines in IntelliJ and even in Eclipse.
Only thing you can do is you can do step over (F8)-which will trace line by line without 
going inside any function.

One more thing is Step out(Shift+F8)- which will go to next debug point directly by executing  in between lines in that single step.

Comment: No. "Resume Program" (F9) will continue until the next breakpoint. Step Out will run the current method and stop the debugger when the method exists.