# Set next statement in Android Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, android-studio

In Visual Studio, I could be debugging a method and I can set next statement to execute.

For example, I could have a loop or a block of code I am currently debugging.  I can right click on a statement before that loop and choose "Set next statement" and my execution point moves to that statement so I can re-trace the loop or a piece of code again.

As an example below, 1 is my current line being debugged.  I could for whatever reason right click on line 2 and set it as next statement and my debugging line moves there so I can retrace all lines in-between:

```java
public class DictionaryDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   // create a new hashtable
   Dictionary dict = new Hashtable();
      
   // add elements in the hashtable
   dict.put("1", "Chocolate"); //<-- 2. I CAN SET THIS AS NEXT STATEMENT
   dict.put("2", "Cocoa");
   dict.put("6", "Coffee");  
      
   // returns the elements associated with the key
   System.out.println(dict.get("6")); //<-- 1. THIS IS CURRENT DEBUGGING LINE
   }
}
```

In Android Studio, I cannot find similar functionality.  Does it exist in Android Studio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How skip line in Intellij idea debug?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462457/how-skip-line-in-intellij-idea-debug)