# How to skip code while debugging in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

I got some method that i dont want to use while debugging the code in Android Studio. For example in Visual Studio you could just drag an arrow (from breakpoint) to wanted line and code between breakpoint and arrow will not be executed. Is there something similar in Android Studio or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good morning Kacper,

I guess that you can find the solution to your question here: [How skip line in Intellij idea debug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462457/how-skip-line-in-intellij-idea-debug)

As Android Studio is based in IntelliJ Community Edition, the debugger works in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

In Intellij we don't have such functionality and maybe studio as well doesn't support it.
Instead you can put a `if` check for the method with `boolean` variable and insert breakpoint over here, as soon as the debugger reaches the `if` change the `boolean` to false. 
Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462457/how-skip-line-in-intellij-idea-debug)

Answer (score -2):

You put two separate Breakpoints and as soon as you reached one, you proceed standard execution which will eventually stop on the next Breakpoint.

Comment: Won't that execute the middle code as well?

Comment: This will execute the code in between that breakpoints.

Comment: Not possible to skip with simple breakpoints, only with flags: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462457/how-skip-line-in-intellij-idea-debug